# Angular, type script annotation does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, annotations

I wrote an annotation to measure the time that took some function to run according to the typescript documentation-

```
export function measureTime(value: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        console.time(value);
        originalMethod.apply(this); //run the original function
        console.timeEnd(value);
    };
}
```

by when I put this annotation in a function by- *@measureTime('some label')*, the annotation does not work, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, the new annotation that works-

```
export function measureTime(value: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        descriptor.value = function(... args: any[]) {
            console.time(value);
            originalMethod.apply(this, args);
            console.timeEnd(value);
        }
    };
}
```